# Identify any events that occurred more than 2 times within in any 12 months period by using R

Tags: r, time, data-cleaning

I have a dataset below:

```
id  event  date
1   A      2010-01-04
2   B      2011-02-11
2   A      2011-05-09
3   A      2005-11-01
1   A      2010-01-05
1   A      2010-08-09
2   A      2011-06-09
2   A      2011-08-25
3   A      2005-05-10
3   A      2001-06-07
1   B      2011-05-09
```

I am using R. For each id, I would like to flag event A that occurred more than 2 times in any 12 months period. The 12 months is not based on calendar year.
Any good suggestions?

Edit:
Here is an algorithm that I thought of but I am not sure how to execute it in R.

1. Filter rows for event A
2. Arrange data frame by id and in descending order of date
3. Group by id
4. Calculate difference in dates between consecutive rows (e.g. row 1 will have difference in dates between row 1 and row 2 given that they are from the same id
5. For each row of an id, count number of events below the row whose differences in time sum up to less than or equal to 12 months. If the count is more than 2, flag the row.

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, your title and description are misleading.

Comment: @RonakShah I have made the amendments. My expected output is the same dataset with an additional flagging variable. e.g. TRUE if the 3 event A for an id happen in a 12 months period and FALSE if only 2 event A occur within a 12 months period. The events doesn't have to be consecutive, meaning event B can happen in between during the duration of 12 months.

Comment: @RYoda Event "B" does not affect the expect results. The data were typed out by me to mimic the confidential data that I eventually will be using the code on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works, albeit inefficient for a big data set that I am working on. Feel free to suggest a more efficient code.

```
df2<-df %>% 
   filter(event=="A") %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(id, desc(date)) %>% 
   mutate(timediff=difftime(date,lead(date),units="days"))

df2$timediff=ifelse(is.na(df2$timediff),0, df2$timediff)

f<-function(id,date,timediff){
 count <- ifelse(max(cumsum(df2$timediff[df2$id==id&df2$date<=date]))<=365, 
           length(df2$timediff[df2$id==id&df2$date<=date]), 
           min(which(cumsum(df2$timediff[df2$id==id&df2$date<=date])>365)))}

df3<-df2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(eventcount=f(id,date,timediff))

df3

Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 9 x 5
    id  event       date timediff eventcount
   <chr> <fctr>     <date>    <dbl>      <int>
1     1      A 2010-08-09      216          3
2     1      A 2010-01-05        1          2
3     1      A 2010-01-04        0          1
4     2      A 2011-08-25       77          3
5     2      A 2011-06-09       31          2
6     2      A 2011-05-09        0          1
7     3      A 2005-11-01      175          2
8     3      A 2005-05-10     1433          1
9     3      A 2001-06-07        0          1
```

Any rows with event count more than 2 will be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with :

```
df <- read.table(text="id event date
1 A 2010-01-04
2 B 2011-02-11
2 A 2011-05-09
3 A 2005-11-01
1 A 2010-01-05
1 A 2010-08-09
2 A 2011-06-09
2 A 2011-08-25
3 A 2005-05-10
3 A 2001-06-07
1 B 2011-05-09", header=T)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, event) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(flag=sum(abs(date-lag(date))<365, na.rm=TRUE)>0)

      id  event       date  flag
   <int> <fctr>     <date> <lgl>
1      3      A 2001-06-07  TRUE
2      3      A 2005-05-10  TRUE
3      3      A 2005-11-01  TRUE
4      1      A 2010-01-04  TRUE
5      1      A 2010-01-05  TRUE
6      1      A 2010-08-09  TRUE
7      2      B 2011-02-11 FALSE
8      2      A 2011-05-09  TRUE
9      1      B 2011-05-09 FALSE
10     2      A 2011-06-09  TRUE
11     2      A 2011-08-25  TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, the outcome is different from what I wanted. Shouldn't the flag for id 3 be all FALSE?

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons here a `data.table` based solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Create the data
df <- read.table(text="id event date
1 A 2010-01-04
2 B 2011-02-11
2 A 2011-05-09
3 A 2005-11-01
1 A 2010-01-05
1 A 2010-08-09
2 A 2011-06-09
2 A 2011-08-25
3 A 2005-05-10
3 A 2001-06-07
1 B 2011-05-09", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)

setDT(df)   # convert to a data.table

df[, `:=`(rowno = 1:.N, date.typed = ymd(date))]  # add a unique row ID + convert date strings into date type
df[, date.window := (date.typed - years(1))]      # add column with with the start date of observations

# Use data.table chaining to:
# 1. Do a non-equi join (1 year time event time window) with event type "A"
# 2. count events per group then
# 3. finally show ordered output
df[df[event == "A"], c(.SD, irowno = i.rowno, i.date = i.date),
   on = .(date.typed >= date.typed, date.window <= date.typed, event == event, id == id),
   by = .EACHI]    [, .(count = .N), by = .(id, event, date, rowno)]   [order(id, -date)]
```

Output:

```
   id event       date rowno count
1:  1     A 2010-08-09     6     3
2:  1     A 2010-01-05     5     2
3:  1     A 2010-01-04     1     1
4:  2     A 2011-08-25     8     3
5:  2     A 2011-06-09     7     2
6:  2     A 2011-05-09     3     1
7:  3     A 2005-11-01     4     2
8:  3     A 2005-05-10     9     1
9:  3     A 2001-06-07    10     1
```

PS: The unique row number is not really required but makes it easier to understand the result and to enrich the original data later...